# HTML javascript onclick event not working on input type submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
function myAlert(){
 alert("yo");
}



/* Recalculate cart */
function recalculateCart()
{
    var subtotal = 0;
  
    /* Sum up row totals */
    $('.product').each(function () {
        subtotal += parseFloat($(this).children('.product-line-price').text());
     });
  
   /* Calculate totals */
  
}


/* Update quantity */
function updateQuantity(quantityInput)
{
    /* Calculate line price */
    var productRow = $(quantityInput).parent().parent();
    var price = productRow.children('.product-price').text();
    var quantity = $(quantityInput).val();
    var linePrice = price * quantity;
  
    /* Update line price display and recalc cart totals */
    productRow.children('.product-line-price').each(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
            $(this).text(linePrice.toFixed(2));
            recalculateCart();
            $(this).fadeIn(fadeTime);
        });
    });  
}


/* Remove item from cart */
function myFunction(removeButton)
{
  /* Remove row from DOM and recalc cart total */
    var productRow = $(removeButton).parent().parent();
    productRow.slideUp(fadeTime, function() {
       productRow.remove();
       recalculateCart();
    });
  return true;
}
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('ecommerce');

  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
 
 ?>
<div class="shopping-cart">
    <div class="column-labels">
        <label class="product-image">Image</label>
        <label class="product-details">Product</label>
        <label class="product-price">Price</label>
        <label class="product-quantity">Quantity</label>
        <label class="product-removal">Remove</label>
        <label class="product-line-price">Total</label>
    </div>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart");
    while($array=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $dbtitle = $array['name'];
     $dbprice = $array['price'];
     $dbdescription = $array['description'];
          $dbproductid = $array['product_code'];

            echo $dbproductid;
?>
  <div class="product">
      <div class="product-image">
      </div>
      <div class="product-details">
          <div class="product-title"><?php echo $dbtitle; ?></div>
              <p class="product-description"><?php echo $dbdescription; ?></p>
         </div>
         <div class="product-price"><?php echo $dbprice; ?></div>
         <div class="product-quantity">
             <input id="quantity-option" type="number" value="2" min="1">
         </div>
   
         <form action="cart.php" method="post">
             <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="remove-product" name="delete" value="Remove">
             <input type="hidden" name="remove_item" value="<?php echo $dbproductid;  ?>">
        </form>
        <div  id="js-price" class="product-line-price"></div>
    </div>
<?php
}

?>
```

When I press submit nothing happen, but when I press onclick `alert()` function alert box will appear. Please help me out. The post juz updated help me to check what's the error. Your help will be much appreciate.

Comment: If you could've just looked up at the console screen, you would've been able to find the error.

Comment: what do u mean the console screen?

Comment: console screen by pressing F12 button there will be a screen appear and at the end of there will be a console tab. Click on console tab and see the error

Comment: well you are not passing any argument to the method myFunction() while you are using a parameter in the function. so pass this to the function.          <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="remove-product" name="delete" value="Remove">

Comment: yup i try myFunction(this) already the code juz return delete sucessful from the php code but the tab bar wont call the javascript function to fade away the cart bar

Answer (score 4):

You do not pass the `removeButton` argument to `myFunction()`. Try:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="remove-product" name="delete" value="Remove">
```

Comment: erm the cart bar juz wont delete fade away but it return delete successful and when i check mysql database the data is sucesfully remove but i want the data to be able to remove and the same time the submit button also able to call the javascript remove fade away function effect

Comment: Well, provide more code please then. From the snippet that you have shown in your post, it is impossible to figure out what the problem is. The only mistake was the absence of the argument.

Comment: to be noted lazarev when i run the myAlert() function it work the pop up box appear

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you don't want the page to be reloaded after submitting data but you still want the animation to be shown and data to be saved?

Comment: actually to correct a little bit is data to be deleted not saved hahaha :)

Comment: In that case, you need to prevent buttons default behavior and overwrite it with an http request. You are using jquery in your example, so you can read about its `ajax` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jquery for the function

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
/* Remove item from cart */
e.preventDefault();
  /* Remove row from DOM and recalc cart total */
  var productRow = $("#btn").parent().parent();
  productRow.slideUp(fadeTime, function() {
    productRow.remove();
    recalculateCart();
  });
  return true;
});
```

Your HTML :-

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
      <input type="submit" id="btn" class="remove-product" name="delete" value="Remove">
        <input type="hidden" name="remove_item" value="<?php echo $dbproductid;  ?>">
    </form>
```

Comment: bro it work but the php function return delete unsuccessful the value cant be deleted what is wrong then?